# 10-hour layover in Nairobi (NBO)

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, transit-visas, connecting-flights, nairobi

I am flying on a Canadian passport to JRO via NBO and I have TWO separate itineraries. The first flight gets me to NBO via Lufthansa at 8:40pm and then the second flight departs NBO via Kenya Airways at 7:30am.

It seems I need to pick up my bags and recheck. Will I need a Kenyan transit visa for this?

Thanks.

Comment: We can't tell you if you need a transit visa if you don't tell us the country which issued your passport...

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas edited for clarity.  Canadian.

Comment: Which airlines are the two different itineraries booked on?

Comment: @gparyani inbound on Lufthansa and out on Kenya Airways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the two flights are booked on separate tickets, and as Lufthansa and Kenya Airways are not interlining partners, you will need to collect your luggage in Nairobi. Because of that, you will need to leave the airport transit area in order to get to baggage claim, and so you will need to cross immigration.

As a Canadian national, you are required to obtain an [e-visa](http://evisa.go.ke/evisa.html) prior to your arrival, applying at least one week, but no more than three months before arrival in Kenya. Be sure to choose the transit visa option, as that has a reduced fee of US $21 (while the standard tourist visa fee is US $51). This visa is valid for stays up to 72 hours. The application process is totally online, and you will receive your result within a few days. Be sure to carry both the printed confirmation of approval and proof of your ticket on Kenya Airways on your flight.

Comment: Thank you.  Not what I wanted to hear, but such is life.  Any input on the second part?

Comment: @dragonspeed What sort of input?

Comment: if there is any generally quiet and safe area to spend 9 nighttime hours in the “general” area of NBO.

Comment: @dragonspeed To include that question here would make this question too broad. Ask a new question about it.

Comment: OK - that was part 2 in the original.

Comment: @dragonspeed Still, it should be its own question. We explicitly disallow asking multiple distinct questions in one post; such posts get closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 0):

You need a transit visa, which can be obtained at the airport at time of transit.

Fill out a form give them cash and fingerprints and you are good to go.

When we travelled (Aug 2018) it took almost TWO hours to clear the visa entry lines.  It was FAR from fast.